# What should I do about this pop up on my android device?

Tags: malware, popup

Any ideas what this is? It keeps popping up randomly on my device. I can be completely ignoring my browser, and going through my gallery and apps and it pops up.

[image: screenshot of mentioned pop up]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, **do *NOT* press the "update now"!!!** That for sure introduces malware. Though batteries *do* have some kind of firmware (mainly for charging control), it is *never ever* updated this way (in fact, it's not updated at all to my knowledge).

Having made clear what you should *not* do leaves the question: What *should* you do about it? You must find out what produces this popup. In 90%+ of all cases, it's a "bad app". So check all apps you've installed shortly<sup>1</sup> before this started. Especially check those apps you've installed from "other sources" (see: [side-loading](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/side-loading/info)). The risk catching such a "bad app" is highest with sources you don't know you can trust. Remove those and see if the issue goes away. If not, as a last-resort you might need to do a [factory-reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info).

If those popups only occur in your browser (the screenshot looks like such an example), it might also be a "bad website". Avoid it then, see if it happens on other sites as well.

For one thing, the popup tells the truth: pressing "update now" has a "high risk level" – you will get worse stuff installed on your device …

---

<sup>**1:** "shortly" is a relative term here; some malware waits up to 30 days before acting such</sup>

Comment: I was thinking, behind the scenes, there must be some permissions that an app would be using here. I don't know much here but I found that restricting many *View* functions using XPrivacy helps a lot. What if someone needs an app but wants to get rid of this pop-up created by the same app? Do you suggest something? I'm open for its dissection :) Factory-reset is always an overkill for me despite having a backup.

Comment: If it's an app behind it, and the pop-ups are "full screen", you might be right about the permission. I'd check e.g. for [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) then.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the possibility of it to be a malware is high, because normal update notifications are too ugly to notify users and this one looks pretty, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Batteries don't have firmware.  That should be enough to dissuade you from falling for this obvious phishing scam.

Comment: If batteries didn't have firmware – how could there be [Faulty Firmware in Lenovo Batteries](http://code.jasonbhill.com/linux/faulty-firmware-in-lenovo-batteries/)? And why then would a DEFCON deal with [Battery Firmware hacking](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEjJhnL02bE)? And why would Lenovo even provide a [Battery Firmware Update Utility](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/docs/ds001322)? But fact is: No battery firmware updates are done the way that popup suggests (via *Google Play*). So the popup is right: pressing that button has a "high risk level" :)

Answer (score 0):

It's just an unwanted pop-up that you should avoid clicking on. Bad websites mostly with extensions .mobi, .biz, (sometimes .com also) etc and all torrent and file hosting websites use these pop-ups for installing malware apps or redirects you to some app the Play Store.
My recommendation:
1. **Use Firefox for Mobile along with the extension AdBlock**. Chrome still doesn't support extensions.
2. Use Maxthon Browser which comes with AdBlock preinstalled.
3. If the device is rooted just install AdBlock from [here](https://adblockplus.org/).